# Reading Wireshark Result and Security Learning Recommendation

Tags: professional-education, snort

I am (not so) currently learning about security and right now I am learning about using Wireshark. I bumped into this video:

http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-detect-network-intrusions-with-wireshark-and-snort-263020/

and one part that interest me is in min 12.42. It is a site that describes the result in details. The problem is, I couldn't see the address clearly, I also didn't really get the name (if you see the video you'll get what I am trying to say)

My questions are:

1. Can anyone please help my finding this site (min 12.42)? I've tried basic search like visiting the author's profile and try googling the article itself but still no luck.
2. Can anyone suggest me a site/reading materials that has a great tutorial about Wireshark result AND noob friendly? I know what things like HTTP, TCP etc. means, but the bottom (hexadecimals?) part of the Wireshark confuses me.
3. Last but not least, do you have any suggestion of where to learn about security premium-way that is not too expensive (like $100 or so, I'm not rich :P). Of course I can learn about it free in Internet but well, it is not so easy (or maybe it is because I don't have a clear learning method/guidelines). I am NOT expecting to be an expert with $100 (and I know that this is not something we can "buy") but I am hoping that at least it can guide me through the noob stage.

Answer (score 1):

I can't view the video from where I am right now, but I'll help as I can.

There are a lot of resources to learn more about Wireshark. Try the [Wireshark University](https://www.lcuportal2.com/) for intro classes (for free as well as paid) and the [documentation](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/) has some nice resources, too.

[Securitytube](http://securitytube.net) has videos for this kind of thing, too.

Wanting to learn about 'security' is a pretty wide topic. Search this forum for the 'professional education' tag for lots of resources, and tell us more specifically about what you are interested in for better results.

Comment: Thank you Schroeder, I'll have a look at your suggestions. You're right, security is a very wide topic, I jumped from one topic to another every time (LOL) so this time I am trying to focus on network sniffing.

Comment: Sniffing is a good place to start. I can't tell you how often knowing things at the packet level helps me understand various security issues. I also recommend reading this site.

Comment: Yup, I believe it will and although I only been through 2 of Stackexchange channels I found them very informative and full of helpful experts :)

Answer (score 1):

this is the website [Portofolio.edu](https://portfolio.du.edu/pc/index) he was talking about
 and also this is his profile http://www.john-strand.com/john-strand/Welcome.html , he is trainer for SANS course , i think this is a part of SANS courses , his YouTube channel is [john strand channel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsWAn2D4ht0)
and his sans page is [John Strand Sans](http://www.sans.org/instructors/John-Strand)
.
for Wireshark there is a course all over the internet about it just Google wireshark network forensics and security video trainings

also in 12:42 he was talking about this http://old.honeynet.org/scans/scan23/sol/Nick/index.html and his profile in https://portfolio.du.edu/pc/index web page is removed i guess

Comment: Thank you. Yes, John Strand, that's him although that is not what I meant in the video. In the video he was using wireshark and then **referring** to someone else's web page and saying that we can get comprehensive guide there. This is the one I am looking for. But still, thanks again, his Youtube channel as well as SANS website is worth watching / browsing around for newbie like me :)

Answer (score 0):

With regard to your second question (reading materials), I would recommend the book "Practical Packet Analysis: Using Wireshark to Solve Real-World Network Problems". Here is a link to it on Amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Packet-Analysis-Wireshark-Real-World/dp/1593271492](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271492)